# How to make the gui and class string be the same?

Tags: wpf

I wrote simple class that on the start it just increase the value of some int every 2 seconds I also added some TextBlock and make the class counter and the TextBlock.Text connecting by Binding.

But the TextBlock is not increase - just show the number '1'
how to increase the value that is shown on the TextBlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wrote simple class that on the start it just increase the value of some int every 2 seconds

Make sure that class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and the int property you're using in the binding is raising `PropertyChanged` correctly.

Also, if you're code to "increase the value every 2 seconds" is happening in a loop on the main (UI) thread, you'll never give the user interface a chance to refresh.  In this case, move the code to increase the value into a timer or a background thread.